# How to I start viewing a YouTube Video at, say, 7 minutes in?

Tags: web-access

It is very easy to load and run a YouTube video, for example via:

```
Button["Jordan Peterson Talk at Harvard --start at 26 min.", 
 SystemOpen[
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqi0jHn_7-I&t=0s&list=\
PL98908E304F5D0395&index=36"]]
```

But how do I begin viewing at, say, minute 26 of the video instead of the beginning?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Not really on topic but your `&t=0s` should be `&t=26m` in the URL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Note that there are functions available to help build URLs. For example, `url = URLBuild[<|
   "Path" -> "https://www.youtube.com/watch",
   "Query" -> {
     "v" -> "qqi0jHn_7-I",
     "t" -> "26m",
     "list" -> "PL98908E304F5D0395",
     "index" -> 36}
   |>]`

Comment: @Edmund (-1) for not using Quantity/UnitConvert etc.

Comment: Thanks Edmond for answering my question and saving me much time.  And thanks @Edmond for making me properly ashamed for asking the question!